# Checking a character on a string

Tags: php, string, character

How can I check every character on a string on php?

For example I have this string.

```
$a = "sd qwerty utr";
```

I want to know the first  of the string and get the 1st 3 characters, then I want to get the last 4 characters of the string.

The output will be `"sd qwe utr"`.

Comment: use PHP function substr()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways (your question doesn't match your description):

1. You can use an index to get to each character individually:

   ```
   $a = "sd qwerty utr";
   $firstchar = $a[0];
   // etc
   ```
2. You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get pieces of the string:

   ```
   $a = "sd qwerty utr";
   $part = substr($a, 0, 3);    // first 3 chars of string
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = substr($a, 0, 3) . substr($a, -4);
```

see here: http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php

Comment: This would just get the first 3 chars.

Comment: The last four characters of the first three characters; are you sane man?

Comment: @BartFriederichs Sorry, it's to early in the morning :-\

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = "sd qwerty utr";

$first=substr($a, 0, 2);

$sec=substr($a, 3, 3);

$third=substr($a, 10, 3);

echo $first." ".$sec." ".$third;
```

This will give you the desired output....

For more reference check php `substr()` manual.....

Answer (score 0):

To produce the output from your example you can try this

```
<?php
$a = "sd qwerty utr";
$ab=explode(' ',$a);
foreach($ab as $i=>$parts)
$ab[$i]=substr($parts,0,3);
$a=implode(' ',$ab);
echo $a;
?>
```